# python common enum in different projects

Tags: python, enums, share

My setup has a manager process running on pc1 and an executing process on pc2. They communicate over rpyc.
Pc2 has 3 cameras attached (it's a robot).

I have used the same class definition in both processes to define my cameras:

```
class CameraList(Enum):
    EYE = 0
    CART = 1
    HEAD = 2
```

I use in both machines the enum values to create a dictionary with further camera definitions

```
config.cameras.update({config.CameraList.EYE: { <eye cam parameters> }})
config.cameras.update({config.CameraList.CART: { <cart cam parameters> }})
```

In the manager process I want to request an image specifying the camera as config.CameraList.EYE in the parameter of my rpyc call.

In the executing process (Pc2) trying to use the parameter to access the cam I get a key error.

Can I only make this work using the "config.CameraList.EYE.value" or "config.CameraList.EYE.name" as parameter because the enum's are created in different processes?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution here would be to use an `IntEnum` -- `IntEnum`s are simply fancy `int`s, and are transferred as `int`s, so on the robot side you'll get the comparison:

```
cameraList.EYE == 0
```

which will evaluate as `True`.

Comment: would have been nice to avoid the .value appendix but the manager still passes a <CamerList.EYE: 0> value to the executer and the executer does not understand this.

Comment: @juerg: you mean the `str` `"<CameraList.EYE: 0>"`?  Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: when looking at the passed in value with pycharm debugger the parameter shows up as ```<CameraList.EYE: 0>``` I am using python 3.7. Maybe this is due to how rpyc works and maybe it is more of a general question how to share classes between different processes?

Comment: @juerg: Sharing classes between different processes is definitely the crux of the problem.  Have you tried using `IntEnum` in both processes instead of plain `Enum`?

Comment: tried it with IntEnum but it's the same issue, trying to print the parameter int the receiver raises a __format__ error and using the parameter a key error.
I have changed now my approach now using only Int's and not enum. I also create the camera class now only in the executer and the manager asks the executer for the camera definitions. This looks also nicer to me as the manager does not have to know how a picture is taken, only gets the image and the camera definitions like FOV, resolution etc. from the executer.
Thanks for your interest and comments!